# Draw a string on a shape

Tags: java, swing

I have an oval and I want to label what it is, for my chess game. I want to use ovals with the names of the pieces on them as strings but I can't seem to get it to work.

Is it even possible to drawString on a shape?

My code

```
    public void drawPieces(Graphics2D g2d){
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        //reds
        if(board[x][y]==24){
            g2d.setColor(Color.red);
            g2d.fillOval(x*80, y*80, 80, 80);
            //drawstring goes here
                            g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
                            g2d.drawString("test", x*80, y*80);
        }
```

Any suggestions are welcome

Edit, my grid method in case it helps.

```
    public void drawGrid(Graphics2D g2d){


    g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 639);
    g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 639, 0);
    g2d.drawLine(0, 639, 639, 639);
    g2d.drawLine(639, 0, 639, 639);

    // draw the horizontal lines using a loop from one to 7, coordiates of each line is (0, x*80, 640, x*80) also
    // draw vertical lines with coordinates of (x*80, 0, x*80, 640)
    for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        g2d.drawLine(0, i*80, 640, i*80);
        g2d.drawLine(i*80, 0, i*80, 640);
    }
    //drawing the black and white squares 
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            if ( (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0) ||  ( row % 2 == 1 &&  col % 2 == 1)  ){
                g2d.setColor(black);
                g2d.fillRect(row*80,col*80,80,80);

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you show _exactly_ what you tried?

Comment: Sure I will put in the edit now.

Comment: Edit, my grid method in case it helps. - not, for better hlp sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only say that it is possible to draw a string over an oval, and I'm doing just that in my own game. The top drawing code should be fine. You just need to check the parameter you pass to the drawing method and the if-condition. Here is the excerpt from my code where i draw
over the oval using slightly different method, but your should work too:

```
public void draw(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(center.x, center.y, itemSize, itemSize));
    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
    g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
    g2d.drawString(itemName, (int)center.x, (int)center.y+18);
}
```

itemName is some string, and just not to confuse I thing that first two parametres to

g2d.fill(...(-,-,itemSize, itemSize)) are not the center of elipse but the top left corner of its sourounding rectangle.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you this worked! I was trying out the font but your way seems to have done the trick :)